# How to set a different base url for each controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, controller

Adding the line `spring.data.rest.basePath=/api` to my `application.properties` file makes it so every endpoint starts with `/api`.

On top of that, I want each controller to "increment" this url. For example, assume I have 2 different controllers, `CustomerController` and `ProviderController`.

If I define in both this function:

```
//CustomerController
@Autowired
private CustomerService service;

@GetMapping("/getById/{id}")
public Customer findCustomerById(@PathVariable int id) {
    return service.getCustomerById(id);
}

//ProviderController
@Autowired
private ProviderService service;

@GetMapping("/getById/{id}")
public Provider findProviderById(@PathVariable int id) {
    return service.getProviderById(id);
}
```

I want the first one to be `/api/customer/getById/{id}` and the second `/api/provider/getById/{id}`.

Is there any way to achieve this without manually having to type it on each annotation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can extract the common part of the path and put it into `@RequestMapping` on your controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/customer")
public class CustomerController {

    // ...

    @GetMapping("/getById/{id}")
    public Customer findCustomerById(@PathVariable int id) {
        return service.getCustomerById(id);
    }
}
```

and

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/provider")
public class ProviderController {

    // ...

    @GetMapping("/getById/{id}")
    public Provider findProviderById(@PathVariable int id) {
        return service.getProviderById(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just double checking. if I do that, I'm overriding the definition on the properties file right? Could I do `@RequestMapping("/api2/customer")`?

Comment: Yes. So in this case your actual endpoint path will be `/api2/customer/getById/{id}`

Comment: @LuisFernandez The `@RequestMapping` on controller is very useful for versioning. It is much easier to create another class with different base path by simply changing `api` to `api2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@RequestMapping("/example/url")` Annotation on your controller.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/url")
class HomeController() {}
```